# Cannot fit bounds in mapbox-gl , in Vue app

Tags: vue.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using vue 2.6.10 and I have the following dependencies [vue-mapbox 0.4.1](https://soal.github.io/vue-mapbox/)  and [mapbox-gl 1.3.2](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js#readme)

The map works, but I cannot get all the points of the map, create bounds and make the map zoom there.

What I am doing now, based on [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/) and [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#lnglatbounds#setsouthwest)

In my template

```
<MglMap 
  ref="map" 
  @load="mapLoaded()">
```

and then in my javascript

```
import Mapbox from "mapbox-gl"; 
components: { Mapbox}
methods :{
   mapLoaded(){
      let coords = [];
      //coords is array , contains arrays like [-118.578, 51.524]
        let bounds = coords.reduce((bounds, coord)=> {
           return bounds.extend(coord);
        }, this.mapbox.LngLatBounds(coords[0], coords[0])
       );

       this.$refs['map'].map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: 20 });

  }
},
created(){
  this.mapbox = Mapbox;      
}
```

This should work, but I keep getting

`TypeError: this.setSouthWest is not a function`

so I guess there is a problem in `this.mapbox.LngLatBounds(coords[0], coords[0])` , maybe the `this.mapbox.` or the `LngLatBounds` does not work. 
If I console log the `coords[0]`, prints an array `[10.467778, 37.600833]`

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you just need to keep debugging until you find the issue.

Comment: @SteveBennett yeah, that the general idea, Anything more particular ? Thanks

Comment: I can't tell you how to debug. But you should be able to narrow down the specific problem more.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error. Turns out I have missed "new" keyword.
You can try adding the "new" keyword for "this.mapbox.LngLatBounds"
The following code worked for me.

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'; 
Vue.prototype.$maps = mapboxgl

    this.map = new this.$maps.Map({container: 'mapContainer', // container ID
                        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
                        zoom: 9 // starting zoom
                    });
    const sourceMarker = new this.$maps.Marker().setLngLat(origin).addTo(this.map);
    const destMarker = new this.$maps.Marker().setLngLat(destination).addTo(this.map);
    const bounds = new this.$maps.LngLatBounds(origin, destination);
    this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
```